# Encode acute accent letters in PHP

Tags: php, urlencode

I'm trying to encode **[acute accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent)** letters in PHP. I used rawurlencode, but it doesn't work for me. I want to encode **ó to %25C3%25B3** for right url. Any ideas how can this be done?

Comment: %25C3%25B3 is `urlencode(urlencode('ó'))` – why do you want to double-encode? Encoding once makes it URL-safe, by encoding a second time you gain nothing.

Comment: Thank you Rik. I want to encode URL this way for API, they use double encoded URLS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to time, I use this in my projects, with success:

```
<a href="teste.php?var=<? echo urlencode(htmlentities("ó p á é"));?>">teste</a>&nbsp;
<?

$var = html_entity_decode($_GET['var']);
echo $var;

?>
```